# Get all attributes or xPath of element in Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, element, webdriver

I'm trying to do simple monkey test for my web page, which get all active elements on page and click on them in random order.

When i do this I want to write a log to know, on which element my test click and on which test crashed

So I want log file to look like this

```
01.01.11 11.01.01 Clicked on Element <span id='myspan' class ='myclass .....>
01.01.11 11.01.01 Clicked on Element <span id='button' class ='myclass title = 'Button'.....>
```

or

```
01.01.11 11.01.01 Clicked on Element //*[@id='myspan']
01.01.11 11.01.01 Clicked on Element //*[@id='button']
```

Is it any way to do in Webdriver + Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way but you could always do something like this (with watir-webdriver):

```
browser.divs.each do |div|
    puts '<span ' + ['id','class','title'].map{|x| "#{x}='#{div.attribute_value(x)}'"}.join(' ') + '>'
end
```

Comment: No, this is not it. I type this elements only by example. Some elements may have 'class', or 'id' attribute, some may not have

Comment: I understand that but I think this is as close as you will get.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver does not provide this type of functionality, you would have to get the page source and do some of your own parsing - I've done this in Html Agility Pack with C#, you would need to find a similar library for ruby (see: [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

1. Get all elements, which are clickable
   For example, find all links, find all clickable spans. Put those candidates in a list
2. Randomly pick a element in that candidate list
3. Click the very element and write some log

Comment: And how would you get the XPath of the element or all of its attributes?

Comment: Why do you using XPath? In automation, XPath is devil. I suggest using id. even class is better than XPath

Comment: XPath itself is not evil, but sometimes the way people use it is pretty bad.  If you know how to use it, it is both powerful and versatile (and not brittle at all), and once you've learned it, there's no going back.

Comment: Agree :) "the way people use it is pretty bad"

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked @pguardiario's answer to come up with this method:

```
def get_element_dom_info(@e)
  if @e.class != Selenium::WebDriver::Element
    raise "No valid element passed: #{@e.class}"
  end
  @attrs = ['id', 'class', 'title', 'href', 'src', 'type', 'name']
  return "<" + @e.tag_name + @attrs.map{ |x| " #{x}='#{@e.attribute(x)}'" if @e.attribute(x) && @e.attribute(x) != "" }.join('') + ">"
end
```

Of course, it expects that the single parameter you pass into it is an actual Selenium element. Also, it doesn't include every possible attribute, but that's the majority of them (and you can always add your extra attributes if needed).

I suppose you can integrate this via some code like this:

```
def clickElement(*args)
  ... # parse vars
  @e = @driver.find_element(...)
  puts get_timestamp + "  Clicked on Element: " + get_element_dom_info(@e)
end
```

**UPDATE** 
I recently realized that I could get the full html of the element using native javascript (d'oh!). You have to use a hack to get the "outerHTML". Here is my new method:

```
def get_element_dom_info(how, what)
  e = @driver.find_element(how, what)

  # Use native javascript to return element dom info by creating a wrapper 
  # that the element node is cloned to and we check the innerHTML of the parent wrapper.
  return @driver.execute_script("var f = document.createElement('div').appendChild(arguments[0].cloneNode(true)); return f.parentNode.innerHTML", e)

end
```